# Pull windowsidentity into mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, label

I need to show the current logged in user in a asp.net 4.5 mvc view. Figured if I had the code in controller for this and did  labelfor in the view, I could get the result I needed. Have tried various things, but nothing is getting this correct. What I have currently is this:

In the home controller:

```
    public String CurrentUserName()
    {
        return System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
    }
```

In my view:

```
    @ViewBag.CurrentUserName();
```

Where am I going worng here? For some reason the two just aren't coming together. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Home controller:

```
public void setCurrentUserName()
{
    ViewBag.CurrentUserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
}
```

And you can use it as `@ViewBag.CurrentUserName` in your View.